# what's the content of "com.example.my.app.Fields" in DataBinding example?

Tags: android, observablelist

when i study Android DataBiding , the page [Work with observable data objects](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#kotlin)  show me how to use ObservableList.

the example code is:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.databinding.ObservableList"/>
    <import type="com.example.my.app.Fields"/>
    <variable name="user" type="ObservableList<Object>"/>
</data>
…
<TextView
    android:text='@{user[Fields.LAST_NAME]}'
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:text='@{String.valueOf(1 + (Integer)user[Fields.AGE])}'
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

but, what's the content of “com.example.my.app.Fields” ？ Fields is a kotlin "object" ? or Fields is a kotlin class with companion object ?

I had tried the two , but get same dataBinding error —— “Couldn't find accessor  xxx.Fields.NAME” 。

Is there anyone can tell me how to define the Fields ? Thanks very much!

Here's my code:

activity_temp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="android.databinding.ObservableArrayList&lt;Object>" />

        <import type="com.databinding.ui.Fields" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <!-- When i use  android:text="@{user[0]}" ，it's ok -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user[Fields.NAME]}"
            tools:text="NAME" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@{user[1]}"
            tools:text="SEX" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Click Here" />
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

TempActivity.kt —— a .kt class file

```
class TempActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityTempBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_temp)

        val user = ObservableArrayList<Any>().apply {
            add("NAME: CnPeng")
            add("SEX：Man")
            add(17)
        }

        binding.user = user

        var clickCount = 0
        binding.bt.setOnClickListener {
            clickCount++
            user[Fields.NAME] = "NAME: CnPeng, ClickNum:$clickCount"
            user[Fields.SEX] = "SEX：Man, ClickNum:$clickCount"
            user[Fields.AGE] = clickCount
        }
    }
}


// Couldn't find accessor  xxx.Fields.NAME
//object Fields {
//    val NAME: Int = 0
//    val SEX: Int = 1
//    val AGE: Int = 2
//}

// Couldn't find accessor  xxx.Fields.NAME
class Fields {
    companion object {
        val NAME: Int = 0
        val SEX: Int = 1
        val AGE: Int = 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

today, i resolved it.

code like this:

```html
// It's ok
//object Fields {
//    @JvmField
//    val NAME: Int = 0
//    @JvmField
//    val SEX: Int = 1
//    @JvmField
//    val AGE: Int = 2
//}

// It's Ok
class Fields {
    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val NAME: Int = 0
        @JvmField
        val SEX: Int = 1
        @JvmField
        val AGE: Int = 2
    }
}
```

i had added @JvmField above field .

because when compile, databinding library genearted a .java class, it's that .java file would call the field in .kt , so ,we need add a annotation.